# either radio button checked or uncheck jquery alert the value of the radio button

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have a radio button which is almost checked when user logged into the system. What I wants to do is when user click the button it should alert where it is checked or unchecked. So I wrote below code to get the value when it checked.
This is html

```
  <input id="radio1" name="radioContacted" value="contacted" type="radio" onclick='docheck02();'   />
```

This is javascript

```
 var checkValue = $("#radio1").val();
alert(checkValue);
```

The problem is this always alert contacted when check box checked or unchecked . Can anyone explain why is that .As I know value should be echo only if radio button is checked. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: I'm not sure how you 'almost' check a radio, but it sounds like you need to use `var checkValue = $("#radio1:checked").val();` instead. Also note that you should use the `change` event with radio/checkbox inputs, and you should also not be using the `onclick` attribute; use unobtrusive event handlers.

Comment: Also a radio does not live on its own. You need at least a pair. If not, use a checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to check if radio is checked then alert its value.

Try this:

```js
var radio = $("#radio1");

if(radio.prop('checked') === true){
    alert(radio.val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="radio1" name="radioContacted" value="contacted" type="radio" checked="checked">
```

Comment: `if ($radio).is(":checked")) alert($radio.val())`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to read the selected radio button value:

```js
function docheck02(){

var checkValue = $('input:radio[name=radioContacted]:checked').val();

alert("Radio Button Value "+checkValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input id="radio1" name="radioContacted" value="contacted" type="radio" onclick='docheck02();'   />
```

Comment: Why not pass the radio to the function. Your code will alert ANY radio with that name - which is of course likely the one clicked